# Gulp: Unable to import Bourbon to stylesheet

Tags: sass, gulp, bourbon, node-sass

I recently did an update to my package.json. Upon importing Bourbon to my scss stylesheet I ran into the following `Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon`.

Within my node-modules, I can see that I have a bourbon-neat and bourbon folder.

I need to understand and fix this for a project I'm currently working on so any help will be appreciated.

**Package.json file**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bourbon": "^4.3.4",
    "bourbon-neat": "^2.1.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

**Gulpfile.js**

```
// Looks insides node_modules for the following 
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var plumber     = require('gulp-plumber');
var uglify      = require('gulp-uglify');
var bourbon     = require('bourbon').includePaths;
var neat        = require('bourbon-neat').includePaths;

var paths = {
    scss: [
        "source/scss/*.scss"
    ]
};

// Kick off server and watch html/scss
gulp.task('build', ['sass'],function(){
      browserSync.init({
        server: "./public"
    });

    gulp.watch('source/scss/**/*.scss',['sass']);
    gulp.watch('public/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// Compile Sass
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.scss)
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ["styles"].concat(bourbon)
        }))
    .pipe(plumber()) // Prevents Gulp from tripping up
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css')) // save output in public css folder
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Task Method
gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug with the packages. `node-neat` and `node-bourbon` are not the official packages. Try swapping them out with [`bourbon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bourbon) and [`bourbon-neat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bourbon-neat).

Also you probably want to update neat to `2.1`. There weren't any breaking changes so you shouldn't have any issues.

---

**Update:**
Also, the addition of bourbon and neat to the sass `importPaths` is not needed and is probably what's causing problems. The contributing page for Neat has a very similar setup to what you are trying to do. Check out https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters/blob/master/Gulpfile.js which is a correctly functioning gulpfile that uses Neat and bourbon.

Here are two examples of how this can work, given your example.

```
var bourbon    = require("bourbon").includePaths,
autoprefix = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
connect    = require("gulp-connect"),
gulp       = require("gulp"),
sass       = require("gulp-sass");

var paths = {
  scss: [
    "source/scss/*.scss"
  ]
};

gulp.task("sass", function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.scss)
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths: ["styles"].concat(bourbon)
    }))
// etc…
```

---

**Update 2:**

I have created and tested a repository that correctly uses Gulp to run bourbon and neat.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/gulp-bourbon-neat-example

It seems that the original guplfile was not adding sass's includepaths correctly. includepaths should be an array that includes direct refferences to bourbon and neat.

Its gulpfile is as follows.

```
var autoprefix = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
    connect    = require("gulp-connect"),
    gulp       = require("gulp"),
    bourbon    = require("bourbon").includePaths,
    neat       = require("bourbon-neat").includePaths,
    sass       = require("gulp-sass");

var paths = {
  scss: ["./source/assets/stylesheets/**/*.scss"]
};

gulp.task("sass", function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.scss)
    .pipe(sass({
        sourcemaps: true,
        includePaths: [bourbon, neat]
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefix("last 2 versions"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./source/assets/stylesheets"))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task("connect", function() {
  connect.server({
    root: "source",
    port: 8000,
    livereload: true
  });
});

gulp.task("default", ["sass", "connect"], function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.scss, ["sass"]);
});
```

Comment: The latest version you've recommended for bourbon-neat is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bourbon-neat) is 1.9.0. Maybe I'm reading this wrong? Anyways I did as you suggested node-neat and node-bourbon for bourbon-neat and bourbon. Still runs into an error on import :(

Comment: @samsos See https://twitter.com/WHMII/status/885884355385712640

> NPM shows 'latest' but what they really mean is 'most recent'. You can view all the available versions with `npm view bourbon-neat versions`

Comment: I see. Thanks. I tried your suggestion and made the swaps but I still get the following error `Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon` ...Its driving me nuts lol

Comment: @samos Ah, found it (i think). You do not need to include bourbon and neat in the sass `includePaths`. Updating original answer.

Comment: includePaths is an array that you need to add to, defining it multiple times just overwrites the previous entry.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion (see above update) and now it can't import Neat :( I've created an issue in [Bourbon repo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/1037), with a link to full source code. I checked out Bitters but can't see Neat in that gulpfile.js :s Sorry for this.